# Why is PowerShell module loading on startup after removing it from profile?

Tags: powershell

I installed https://github.com/vors/ZLocation per its instructions. Then when I open `$PROFILE.CurrentUserAllHosts` and comment the `Import-Module ZLocation` line and restart PowerShell, I can still use the alias which that module provides (`z`). This happens for other modules as well. How are the aliases from the module still available if the Import-Module statement isn't running?

I also confirmed I have none of the [other](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/understanding-the-six-powershell-profiles/) PowerShell profiles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Preface**:

- It follows from the next section that there is normally *no* good reason to import `Install-Module`-installed modules *explicitly* via `$PROFILE` files.
- The reason that the installation instructions for the [`ZLocation`](https://github.com/vors/ZLocation) module nonetheless call for doing so is owed to the module's specific purpose: it wants to monitor current-location (current-directory) changes *from the very start of every session*, which therefore requires explicit importing via `$PROFILE`; by contrast, module auto-loading (see next section) only imports modules *on demand*.

---

PowerShell has a [module auto-loading](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_modules#module-auto-loading) feature that is *enabled by default*.

- That is, if the [`$PSModuleAutoLoadingPreference` preference variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Preference_Variables#psmoduleautoloadingpreference) isn't set (the default) or is set to `'All'`, modules in the locations listed in the [`$env:PSModulePath` environment variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_PSModulePath) are *automatically* imported, *on demand*, namely as soon as you reference one of their commands for the first time in a session.

[`Install-Module`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/powershellget/install-module) invariably installs to a location covered by auto-loading (PowerShell itself ensures that certain well-known locations are always present in `$env:PSModulePath`).

- Thus, with `$PSModuleAutoLoadingPreference` undefined or set to `'All'`, modules installed with `Install-Module` are auto-loaded on demand, independently of any explicit [`Import-Module`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/import-module) statements that happen to be present in one of your [`$PROFILE` file(s)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Profiles)

---

Therefore, removing the `Import-Module` statement from `$PROFILE` is by itself *not* enough to prevent loading the module in question.

Depending on your intent, there are several options:

- If you simply want to *uninstall* a module, use [`Uninstall-Module`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/powershellget/uninstall-module):

  ```bash
   # May require elevation if originally installed with -Scope AllUsers
   Uninstall-Module ZLocation
  ```
- If you want to disable auto-loading altogether:

  ```bash
   # Disable auto-loading altogether.
   $PSModuleAutoLoadingPreference = 'None'
  ```
- If you want to make auto-loading contingent on prefixing commands with the name of the source module, e.g. `SomeModule\Get-Foo`:

  ```bash
   # Only auto-load when commands are module-qualified.
   $PSModuleAutoLoadingPreference = 'ModuleQualified'
  ```
- If you want to keep the default auto-loading behavior but exempt a specific module from it:

  - Move the module's folder to a location *not* listed in `$env:PSModulePath`

    - You can discover a module's folder as follows:

      ```bash
      Split-Path (Get-Module -ListAvailable SomeModule).Path
      ```
  - You'll then need to pass this location to `Import-Module` in order to load the module.

Note: Setting `$PSModuleAutoLoadingPreference` takes effect instantly, whenever executed and affects subsequent calls in the same session. You may therefore place a statement that sets it in your `$PROFILE` file(s) do determine the default auto-loading behavior for your sessions (though note that the `-NoProfile` CLI parameter can be used to *suppress* profile loading).

Comment: To disable auto-loading can that `$PSModuleAutoLoadingPreference = 'ModuleQualified'` go in the `$PROFILE.CurrentUserAllHosts` file? Is the profile evaluated early enough in PowerShell initialization?

Comment: @LironYahdav, yes, setting `$PSModuleAutoLoadingPreference` takes effect instantly, so you can place it in any profile file that is loaded into a given session.